# How to create a submit button?

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, powerapp

I'm new to SharePoint and was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ps7jB5RDoWI&t=484s) webinar on how to use SharePoint for knowledge management. At 11:24 they use a submit knowledge button to submit the selected document to the knowledge management site for approval and also get the option to add information about the document as well. Does anybody know how the button is added to the menu and how the flow is created?
Thanks

Comment: The menu button is "Custom Action" similar to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/create-custom-actions-to-deploy-with-sharepoint-add-ins and flow might be URL based trigger for example: https://powerautomate.microsoft.com/fr-fr/blog/call-flow-restapi/